# my update code can't working in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

Actually, I editing the post in my blog but when I tried it cant update instead of it creating a new record. I also tried update() function but it can't work. What's wrong with the code? Anyone, please give me some suggestions to improvise my code. I want to understand what's the problem. So, anybody can explain in detail then I will really appreciate this thing.

My Code:

PostController Code:

```
public function update(Request $request,Post $post)
    {
     
        $post->user_id=$request->user()->id;
        $post->title=$request->title;
        $post->Description=$request->description;
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/show');
    }
```

Route file Code:

```
Route::get('posts/edit/{edit}',[PostController::class,'edit']);
Route::post('/update',[PostController::class,'update']);
```

View Page Code:

```
<form method="POST" action='/update'>
      @csrf
      <table class="table table table-striped table">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-form-label text-md-right">Title</label><br/>
    <input placeholder="Enter title here" type="text" name="title" value="{{$data->title}}" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-form-label text-md-right">Description</label>
  </div>
    <div>
    <textarea name="description" required>{{$data->description}}
    </textarea></div>
  <div>  
    <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" required />
  </div>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you can try to use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) your route will be like this: `Route::post('/update/{post}',[PostController::class,'update']);`

Comment: okay, now its working properly thank you so much brother.